# receive "Error reading from database" when changing profile's email address in Moodle 3.11.2

Tags: database, moodle

I'm a Moodle administrator that I recently changed the site's operating system from Centos to Ubuntu and also upgraded the version of Moodle from 3.9 to 3.11.2. Everything was going well until I wanted to change the email address of my profile (or that of other users), that I got an "error reading from database" error message.
[(Error message)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9iyI.png)
Therefore, the Moodle does not allow changing the email address.

I am asking for guidance and help from users who have experience in solving this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to peruse the logs? No chance to have any idea of what's going on without looking into db/web server/php logs.

Comment: I saw the php error_log file, but the entry related to the mentioned error is not inserted in it.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging in Moodle's config.php file ?
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');         // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1; 

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Debugging#In_config.php

Comment: The problem was solved by changing the database collation from 'utf8mb4_general_ci' to 'utf8_general_ci' in config.php file.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the dbcollation was `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, so I simply changed it to `utf8_unicode_ci`

Kept getting the error when trying to add a New User or change the email address of a User, like Ali.  Not sure if Softaculous update from 10.5 to 11 was to blame, since hadn't tried to add/update any users from 3.11 through to our latest 3.11.4 incremental updates.

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. We have spent 3 working days to find a solution. Finally, this solution works. Thanks.